# Large file uploads failing php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, large-file-upload

I've made a tiny site where my friends can upload songs and some tiny files that they want to but my problem is that files over 5mb fails, as in the browser shows "Connection reset" error.

The max file size set by my server is 2Mb, but i can upload 2.5-3Mb fine
Probably because i overwrote it with .htaccess

But however file uploads over 5Mb they just don't get uploaded at all, as i said earlier browser cannot reach server.

Would this be a server issue? Or an issue in my code? Will i need to change things in order for large uploads to happen?
Also max post size and max file size is set to 40mb in the .htaccess file

Here is the website
http://sharebay.webatu.com/

You can try uploading some files over 7mb, mp3/flac/aac/m4a/wav/

Answer (score 4):

Add these to .htaccess as well (adjust 10M to size in MB that you want):

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 10M
```

This assumes you don't have access to php.ini (otherwise it would be better to put there) and that your host does not prohibit htaccess overrides on these values.

If you've already tried that then post more info about your environment.  If you are on a shared server it's probably not something you can change too much.

Comment: Looks like shared hosting so probably not much more you can do other than try modifying htaccess as has been said.  Or if you know Linux at all try a VPS, they are really cheap these days and you can do pretty much anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

Change file upload size

You can change it an .htaccess file.

.htaccess files are stored in the same directory as your .php files are. They modify configuration for that folder and all sub-folders. You simply use them by creating an .htaccess file in the directory of your choice (or modify it if present).

The following should enable you to increase your upload limit (if the server provider allows PHP config changes via .htaccess).

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 70M
php_value post_max_size 80M
php_value memory_limit 90M
php_value max_execution_time 240
php_value max_input_time 240
```

you can change size according ur need

Answer (score 0):

How long the upload takes?

If you have slow upload line then it should take more time then [max_execution_time](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) and then apache halts your PHP script.

Comment: is the max executing in seconds?